# Out String Parameter Not Returned From COM Interop

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

I have a ATL COM component method which has an [out] BSTR* parameter. I have create a reference to this component from my .NET application which treats the parameter as an out String type. The COM component allocates this string like this:

```
    USES_CONVERSION;
    *sText = SysAllocString(T2OLE(psText));
```

where psText is a char*

However, when the method call returns, the .NET code still has an empty string. Can anyone see what is wrong?

Comment: Can you post full function here? Its declaration and what is actually psText?

Comment: Which version of ATL are you using?

Comment: You should use A2OLE() when psText is a char*.

Comment: Does this call need marshaling (called interprocess or .NET and COM component not in the same apartment) ?

Comment: What difference would that make to the return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code isn't wrong but the .Net runtime may be too stupid to parse the indirection. You might want to rephrase your IDL from:

```
HRESULT DoSomething([in] BSTR arg, [out] BSTR *result);
```

to:

```
HRESULT DoSomething([in] BSTR arg, [out, retval] BSTR *result);
```

The first syntax will yield in C#:

```
string result;
void DoSomething(string arg, out result);
```

2nd:

```
string result = DoSomething(arg);
```

Any 8-bit to 16-bit Unicode conversion must go through SysAllocString, since both `out` and `out, retval` require the caller to free the string. However, the .Net-runtime might get better results if it is told that this is the return value;

Comment: That didn't make any difference. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If your ATL COM component is compiled with the UNICODE flag, T2OLE will do nothing. If psText is really a char *, you must use A2OLE to be sure the string is converted to UNICODE.
.NET marshaling code doesn't support 'binary BSTR', that is BSTR with non UNICODE characters.

Comment: It's not compiled with the UNICODE flag

Answer (score 0):

You would not have the CHAR/WCHAR issues if you replaced your

```
*sText = SysAllocString(T2OLE(psText));
```

with

```
*sText = CComBSTR(psText).Detach();
```

CComBSTR constructor would apply conversion automatically.

Comment: This made no difference either